# Why would App Engine shut down an instance for ~12 hours when it should be receiving a 50% split of all traffic?

Tags: google-app-engine

I've configured App Engine to split traffic 50/50 between two versions:

[image]

However, App Engine shut down the one instance of the new version of the app a few hours after it was created:

[image]

The instance was created around the time that I configured the traffic split, but it was inexplicably shut down at 8pm.

This morning I checked my logs and noticed that the new version wasn't getting any traffic, so when I logged back into the Cloud console around 9:30am today, the instance spun back up and traffic started flowing again.

Here are the utilization charts for the different versions:

[image]

[image]

Why would App Engine shut down an instance that is supposed to be receiving 50% of traffic? Why would it seemingly fix itself as soon as I started looking into the problem? And is there anything I should do to ensure this doesn't happen again?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that traffic is so low to this site that App Engine reclaims underutilized instances. Still, I'd expect it to start up a new instance for a version that is configured to receive half of traffic.